# How to save data from TextForm to a List

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a simple app, in which I have class Task which is displayed in Card class on my HomePage. I have floatingActionButton by which I can add new Tasks in AlertDialog, but there is a problem. When I want to add new Task I receive this
[image: error].

```
My HomePage class looks like this:

    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

    List<Task> tasks = [
    Task(title: "Task4",text: "text of task 4"),
    Task(title: "Task5",text: "text of task 5"),
    Task(title: "Task6",text: "text of task 6"),
  ];

  var myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[100],

      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[500],
        title: Text("Task Manager"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),

      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: tasks.map((task) => TaskCard(
            task: task,
            delete: (){
              setState(() {
                tasks.remove(task);
            });
          },
        )).toList(),
      ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context){
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text("New task"),
                content: TextFormField(
                  controller: myController,
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("Submit"),
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        Task t = new Task();
                        t.title = myController.text;
                        tasks.add(t);
                      });
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            }
          );
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[500],
          ),
    
        );
      }

}
```

And of course, I have Task.dart and TaskCard.dart.

Task class:

```
class Task {

  String title;
  String text;

  Task({this.text, this.title});
}
```

TaskCard class:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Task.dart';

class TaskCard extends StatelessWidget{

  final Task task;
  final Function delete;
  TaskCard({this.task, this.delete}); 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0,10.0,10.0,5.0),
      color: Colors.blueGrey[200],
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              task.title,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
            Text(
              task.text,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
            FlatButton.icon(
              onPressed: delete,
              label: Text("Done"),
              icon: Icon(Icons.done),
              color: Colors.blueGrey[300],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share `Task.dart` and `TaskCard.dart` too ?

Comment: Of course, I edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is because you are setting new `Task`'s `title`..

```
t.title = myController.text;
```

..but not setting the new `Task`'s `text` property.

Try changing the `onPressed` to this and see if the problem persists..

```
onPressed: (){
   setState(() {
       Task t = new Task();
       t.title = myController.text;
       t.text = '';
       tasks.add(t);
   });
   Navigator.of(context).pop();
},
```

Comment: No, I'm just setting the value to a title of my Task class which looks like this class Task {

  String title;
  String text;

  Task({this.text, this.title});
}

Comment: Not setting the `text` property when making a new `Task` looks like the problem.

Comment: I just tried it with the `t.text = '';` change and it is working fine for me. I see the new task added to the `Column` without any error.

Comment: check out the code on dartpad to try it out - https://dartpad.dev/d91ad2556e0bcd56ce2ae8c6739b7410

Comment: not working for me https://imgur.com/xw6gykM . Can you send me your code?

Comment: You can see the code on the dartpad link which I shared in my last comment. Also, not sure but try re-running your project and then try.

Comment: THANK YOUUU so much it worked!!! I restarted the app and it worked. And i missed the initState() function, maybe that was the problem. thank you